# How to calculate this integral as following?

Tags: integration, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

Can someone give me an idea, how to derive the integration?
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-e^{t}}t^{k}\mathrm{d}t~\text{for}~k\in \mathbb
N^{+}.$$
I found that the function may has a connection with the Gamma function or the Meijer G-function, but I can not know haow to solve this problem.

Comment: Its solution can be written as MeijerG functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function

Comment: Thank you for your helpful hints. I have know there are some connections between the MeijerG function and the integration above. But I am interested in the detailed calculation and the relation to Gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I_k=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-e^{t}}\,t^{k}\,dt$$
As far as I know, there is no other representation of this integral beside the Meijer G hypergeometric function (except for $k=0$) provided $k$ to be an integer (if $k$ is not an integer, I do not know any formula).

The patterm is very simple
$$I_1=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

$$I_2=2 \,G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1 \\
 0,0,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

$$I_3=6 \,G_{4,5}^{5,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1 \\
 0,0,0,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ that is to say
$$I_k=k! \,G_{k+1,k+2}^{k+2,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1,\cdots \\
 0,0,0,0,0,\cdots
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

If you want a table of numerical values, let me know and I shall edit.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Is there a detailed process of the result? Or can we derive it by induction? I am also interested in its relation to the Gamma function, could you please give some hints or satements about it? Thank you again.