# Double exponential gamma type integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, approximation, gamma-function

The gamma function is an integral of the form $$\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^n \,dt = n!$$

One can even throw in a coefficient without much trouble $$\int_0^\infty e^{-at} t^n  \,dt = \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}$$

But if we want to decay even faster, like $$\int_0^\infty e^{-e^t} t^n  \,dt = ?$$ then a close approximation seems difficult, much less an exact answer. The new integral DOES decay far faster; for n=25 I get around 34,000 in comparison to 25! for the gamma function.

What is the best known approximation to this integral? My end goal is an approximation of $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda e^{t/x}} t^{2n}  \,dt = ?$$ where we fix $\lambda,x>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3967759/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463272/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the references. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $$I_n=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda\, e^{t/x}}\, t^{n}  \,dt=x^{n+1} \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda\, e^{u}}\, u^{n}  \,du$$

Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967759/how-to-calculate-this-integral-as-following/3967831#3967831)

$$I_n=n!\, x^{n+1} \,G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(\lambda\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1,\cdots \\
 0,0,0,0,0,\cdots
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the details.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici If your willing to indulge my ignorance further, I have posted a similar type of problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547766/exponential-decaying-double-integral