# Exponential decaying double integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, estimation

I am having trouble with the following function, fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $$f(x)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{10s-3e^{4s}\cosh(t)} s^{2n} \cos(xt) ds dt$$

Is this function positive for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? I think it is, but am having trouble bounding the kernels. In particular, if it is negative, do we have bounds of where it can be negative? Does it only achieve being negative in one interval?

Comment: Do not forget $ds\,dt$ or whatever

Comment: Added for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a partial result.*

If we consider the inner more general integral
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty  e^{a s+b e^{c s} \cosh (t)}\,s^{n} \,\cos (x t )\,ds$$ Mathematica provides answers for specific values of $n$. Using $d=\frac{a+c}{c}$

$$I_1= +\frac{1! }{a^2}\cos (x t ) \,\,
   \, _2F_2\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c};d,d;b \cosh (t)\right)$$
$$I_2= -\frac{2! }{a^3}\cos (x t ) \,\,
   \, _3F_3\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c};d,d,d;b \cosh
   (t)\right)$$
$$I_3=+\frac{3! }{a^4}\cos (x t )\,\,
   _4F_4\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c};d,d,d,d;b \cosh (t)\right)$$
$$I_4=-\frac{4! }{a^5}\cos (x t )\,\,\,
   _5F_5\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\frac{a
   }{c};d,d,d,d,d;b
   \cosh (t)\right)$$
and I suppose that we can conjecture
$$I_n=(-1)^{n+1} \frac {n!}{a^{n+1}}\cos (x t )\,\,\,_{n+1}F_{n+1}\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{a}{c},\cdots;d,d,\cdots;b
   \cosh (t)\right)$$ These integrals can also write in terms of the Meijer G-functions.

Now, I do not think that, even for fixed  value of $(n,a,b,c)$, we could compute explicitly
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty I_n\,dt$$

From a numerical point of view, the integration seems to be very difficult.

Trying for $J_2$ and $J_4$ with $a=10$, $b=-3$, $c=4$ for small velues of $x$, they *seem* to be negative (probably because of the $(-1)$ in front).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. We know, $f(0)$ is positive since the integrand is positive when $x=0$, hence for some small neighborhood around zero, we know $f$ is positive. Also, $f$ is an even function, so we only need concern ourselves with $x>0$. However, even in the simplest case, $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-e^s \cosh(t)} \cos(x t) ds dt$$ it is not obvious to me this is positive for all $x>0$, but I can't find a counter-example. We do know that $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-e^s t^2} \cos(x t) ds dt > 0$$ for all $x>0$ as can be easily checked.

Comment: I have been trying to find a limit argument, but haven't been able to, yet.

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-e^s \cosh(t)} \cos(x t)\, ds\, dt=\int_0^\infty \cos (x t )\, \Gamma (0,\cosh (t))\,dt$$ *should* look like a distribution function.  Numerically, it is positive for any $x$ but this is not a proof. (to be continued, I hope)

Comment: Play with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BCos%5Bt+2%5D+Gamma%5B0%2C+Cosh%5Bt%5D%5D%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D+

Comment: Another similar one is $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-e^s e^t} \cos(x t) ds dt$$ which I believe is $$\frac{i}{2|x|}(E_{1+xi}(1)-\Gamma(xi,1))$$ for $x>0$, which I think is positive, but haven't verified. It makes me wonder if all increasing functions $g$, make $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-e^s g(t)} \cos(x t) ds dt > 0\ \ \ ?$$

Comment: I have simplified the kernel. It was not obvious, but integration by parts produces an anti-derivative. Hence I have reformulated the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558729/non-obvious-positive-sine-transform