# Non-obvious positive sine transform?

Tags: inequality, fourier-transform

For each $x>0$ define, $$F(x)=\int_0^\infty \tanh(t)e^{-\cosh(t)} \sin(x t) dt$$

Is it the case that $F$ is positive for all $x>0$? This appears to be the case, when I do approximations. This kernel is not decreasing,  since $\tanh$ is zero at zero, and so a proof appears to be very complicated. Does anyone know of a reference or a proof? Or a counter-example?

Comment: It seems to be true from numerical calculations with very high accuracy.

Comment: If an exact computation is hoped, one should turn to integration on complex functions (residue theorem, etc.)

Comment: @JeanMarie What exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: I have posted this as a research question since this may be an open problem, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432958/when-does-the-sine-transform-result-in-a-positive-function